# A smidgeon meta

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

The sentence on the other side of this post is false.

The sentence adjacent to that sentence is not needed, but take the sentence out and the post falls apart.

This post doesn't make sense, but then this post does make sense.

The sentences in this post are each manifestly self-consistent.

This post is self-consistent.

The sentence on the other side of this post is true.

---

Hint 1

> The sentence "this post is self-consistent" is true (it'd be a pretty lame puzzle if it weren't). Look for weaknesses in the sentences that seem to be contradictory. What does "the other side of this post" mean?

Hint 2

> Take out the word "manifestly" and the post is harder to crack.

Hint 3

> The goal is to try to figure out how this post could make sense. Imagine that this post was written in some context, and that somebody stumbles on these sentences while noting that context. In their eyes everything would make sense. In our eyes, isolated and left alone, things don't make sense. Try to find the context.

Hint 4

> As the title suggests, this puzzle is entirely intrinsic. Its resolution does not refer to any outside objects or events. As mentioned in the third hint, the answer would be obvious to anyone finding this puzzle in context, and yet the outside context is irrelevant. The answer is in the presentation. Find how this puzzle is presented. Find what this puzzle is written on.

Comment: I don't understand what is expected as an answer.

Comment: @flashstorm This is a little tricky to explain without giving away the answer, hence the enigmatic tag. At face value, the post makes no sense -- it seems to be self-contradictory, and yet I promise it isn't. If you ... umm ... interpret it the right way, it makes perfect sense. Let me know if you want me to be more explicit.

Comment: @flashstorm This is my second puzzle, so let me know if I've been too vague and should add a second, more direct hint.

Comment: The post doesn't... ask for anything though? Like, there's no question, no indication of what is being looked for...

Comment: @flashstorm I added another hint to clarify.

Comment: @QuantumFool is the title important at all?

Comment: @Brandon_J See hint 4. Beyond that ... well, I'll see if anyone gets it after the newest hint before helping any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since this post has 6 lines, my guess would be that they are in the form of a cylinder.

The sentence on the other side of this post is false.

> i.e. hint 4 is false. Since every sentence is not manifestly self consistent, this is
> **TRUE**

The sentence adjacent to that sentence is not needed, but take the sentence out and the post falls apart.

> Hint 3 is possibly obvious, but if it was taken out, there would be no definite opposite sentences.
> **TRUE**

This post doesn't make sense, but then this post does make sense.

> As shown by @Ben Barden, it doesn’t make sense to the reader… until it does.
> **TRUE**

The sentences in this post are each manifestly self-consistent.

> Again, as shown by @Ben Barden, incorrect.
> **FALSE**

This post is self-consistent.

> It *is* one of the hints, after all!
> **TRUE**

The sentence on the other side of this post is true.

> Hint 3 is true, so this is correct.
> **TRUE

Original answer:

> Since this post has 6 lines, my guess would be that the first three are on one side of the page and the other three on the second side.

The sentence on the other side of this post is false.

> i.e. hint 4 is false. Since every sentence is not manifestly self consistent, this is
> **TRUE**

The sentence adjacent to that sentence is not needed, but take the sentence out and the post falls apart.

> Hint 5 is possibly obvious, but if it was taken out, the post would be harder to split into two sides.
> **TRUE**

This post doesn't make sense, but then this post does make sense.

> As shown by @Ben Barden, it doesn’t make sense to the reader… until it does.
> **TRUE**

The sentences in this post are each manifestly self-consistent.

> Again, as shown by @Ben Barden, incorrect.
> **FALSE**

This post is self-consistent.

> It *is* one of the hints, after all!
> **TRUE**

The sentence on the other side of this post is true.

> Hint 3 is true, so this is correct.
> **TRUE**

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was thinking of, but it's very, very close, so I might as well give you the rest. Gur fragraprf ner jevggra ba n plyvaqre, fb gur svefg naq sbhegu ner bccbfvgr, gur frpbaq naq svsgu ner bccbfvgr, naq gur guveq naq fvkgu ner bccbfvgr. Nf lbh pbeerpgyl qvfprearq, gur svefg fragrapr vf gehr orpnhfr gur sbhegu fragrapr vf snyfr, naq gur fvkgu fragrapr vf gehr orpnhfr gur guveq fragrapr vf gehr. ...

Comment: ... Ubjrire, gur fragrapr nqwnprag gb gur sbhegu fragrapr vf abg gur svsgu fragrapr (juvpu vf qrsvavgryl arrqrq) ohg gur guveq fragrapr (gurl'er obgu nqwnprag, ohg gung'f gur bar V'z ersreevat gb). Vg whfg qrfpevorf ubj nyy chmmyrf jbex, naq vg'f cerggl zhpu svyyre. Ubjrire, vs lbh gnxr vg bhg gura lbh unir n cragntba bs fragraprf naq abg n urkntba, fb gurer vf ab fvatyr fragrapr ba gur bgure fvqr bs nal fragrapr naq gur svefg naq ynfg fragraprf znxr ab frafr. Again, great job! I'll accept when you adjust the answers.

Comment: Thanks! Rot13(V thrff V arire gubhtug bs n plyvaqre, bayl gjb fvqrf bs n cntr.)

Answer (score 2):

> 42.  "True" is counted as 1, "False" is counted as 0, and the whole thing is evaluated in binary.  Also, it's a HHGTTG reference.

The sentence on the other side of this post is false.

> True? not clear on what "on the other side of this post" means, given that the most obvious meaning would not be self-consistent.  Guess based on the reference.

The sentence adjacent to that sentence is not needed, but take the sentence out and the post falls apart.

> False: All sentences are needed, just to get the bits to line up right.

This post doesn't make sense, but then this post does make sense.

> True: It doesn't make sense to the reader... until it does.

The sentences in this post are each manifestly self-consistent.

> False: the previous sentence is not at all manifestly self-consistent

This post is self-consistent.

> True: Also a gimme, given the hints.

The sentence on the other side of this post is true.

> False? not clear on what "on the other side of this post" means, given that the most obvious meaning would not be self-consistent.  Guess based on the reference.

Comment: Interesting thinking, but unfortunately not what I was going for. Re sentences 1 and 6: as noted in hint 1, you have to figure out what "other side" means -- it's not just something to be ignored. Re 2: your complaint is exactly what the second part of the sentence qualifies, so you actually illustrated why that sentence should be true. Still, you're off to a good start thinking about which sentences are right and wrong.